# Как найти длину самого короткого слова в строке?

Tags: javascript

Перевел строку в массив. Подскажите, почему не получается отсортировать?

```js
function findShort(s) {
  var arr = [];
  arr.push(s.match(/\w+/g));
  arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.length - b.length;
  });
  return arr[0].length
}
console.log(findShort("bitcoin take over the world maybe who knows perhaps")
```

Comment: вы забыли поставить скобку в конце console.log, получите в итоге 9

Comment: Спасибо помогли. Но очень хотелось бы узнать что не так в моем коде, кроме пропущенной в конце скобки) Поправил, все работает function findShort(s) { var arr = s.match(/\w+/g); arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a.length - b.length; }); return arr[0].length }

Comment: вы кладете массив в массив вот тут:   arr.push(s.match(/\w+/g));

Comment: У вас в массиве arr оказывается ровно один элемент - массив слов. Далее сортировка смысла не имеет, а потом вычисляется длина этого массива слов. Метод [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) принимает аргументы по одиночке.

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы узнать информацию о самом коротком слове, не нужно сортировать массив — можно воспользоваться функцией [Math.min()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min).

```js
var s = "bitcoin take over the world maybe who knows perhaps"
var a = s.split(/\W+/)
var l = a.map(e => e.length)
var r = Math.min(...l)

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 2):

Другой ответ лучше в том плане что для выяснения самого короткого слова сортировка не нужна, тут мы ищем самое короткое слово а потом уже выводим его длину:

```js
function findShort(s){
 return s.split(" ").sort(function(a,b){
   return a.length - b.length;
 }).shift()
}
console.log(findShort("bitcoin take over the world maybe who knows perhaps").length)
```